# How to boot Ubuntu 14.04 on an Macbook pro intel

Tags: 14.04, boot, mac

How to boot Ubuntu 14.04 from an USB drive on a Macbook pro intel

Comment: Have you tried inserting the USB and then restarting the machine to see if it boots from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have done the bootable USB already shut down the MBP and when powering it on leave the left Alt button pressed and then select the pendrive to boot.